# Different outputs of computeMatrix depending on binsize

Tags: deeptools

I'd like to output a figure in +/-1kb around a center using [computeMatrix](http://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/computeMatrix.html) as following command:

```
computeMatrix reference-point -S data.bw -R centers.bed -a 1000 -b 1000 -bs=10 -out newdata10.gz --referencePoint center
```

The bed file is like:

```
chr1 100 101
```

If I change `-bs=1`, two outputs of the same input newdata10.gz are quite different. Which's correct with my commands? Maybe I don't understand the meaning of binsize option.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't send things like this to the deepTools mailing list and post them here.

As I mentioned on the list, what you're likely being surprised by is that computeMatrix is not summing values, but taking the average in each bin. You can change this with the `--averageTypeBins` option (the default is `mean`, you presumably want `sum`).

**Update**: For those wondering the cause of the confusion was due to not using `--missingDataAsZero`. In other words, including or not including NAs will lead to different results, since different numbers of values will be included.

Comment: Hi, Ryan,
     The plot for is bin window=10bp to average in another way is attached. Please note the y-axis. The peak (>0.2) is much larger than the one (~0.05) with binsize=10bp from computeMatrix. I'm confused on this. Is the value in with binsize=10bp from computeMatrix really mean or median or some other ways?
    sorry I can not attach the figure here.
    Thanks

Comment: The default is `mean`, so unless you change it that's what you're getting.